# Python requests invalid header value

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, cookiejar

I have exported a cookies.txt file from firefox using a cookie export addon. Im trying to use the cookie file with python requests but getting this...

> ValueError: Invalid header value

My code:

```
import requests
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
cj.load('cookies.txt', ignore_discard=True)
r = requests.get('blah.com', cookies=cj)
```

What can I do?

Comment: `cookielib` has been renamed to `http.cookiejar` in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/http.cookiejar.html?highlight=cookie#module-http.cookiejar). Confirm the version of Python.

Comment: Im using python 2

Comment: I've tested this on Python 3.6 and it works. As I do not have Python 2.7, I could not test it. I've edited the code further as it might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.7 version:

```
import os
import cookielib
import requests
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
cookiepath = os.getcwd()
cj.load(os.path.join(cookiepath, 'cookies.txt'))
r = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com', cookies=cj)
```

Python 3.6 version(tested):

```
import os
import http.cookiejar
import requests
cj = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar()
cookiepath = os.getcwd()
cj.load(os.path.join(cookiepath, 'cookies.txt'))
r = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com', cookies=cj)
print(r.cookies)  #<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='prov', value='619.....1a9f2f'....rfc2109=False)]>
print(r.headers) #{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN'...}
```

"cookies.txt" must be a Netscape format cookies file. There are [Firefox add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/reviews/?page=2) available to export cookies in this format. Also, make sure that the file is in the current working directory path for the above code to work.

Comment: Still not working... Invalid header value. The cookies.txt is in a netscape format cookies file.

Comment: In that case, you may execute the Python 2.7 code line by line in IDLE and see where exactly the error appears. Unfortunately, my dev environment only supports 3.6. I'm wondering whether the cookie file loads in the first place, execute the line `cj.load(os.path.join(cookiepath, 'cookies.txt'))` and see if you get an error.